# System.Drawing.Common is not supported on this platform, but i am on Windows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core

I am Java dev, but my university forces me to develop course work in winforms C#. The core concepts are very similar, so its no problem.
I will need to draw some things on my form, so i am taking `PaintEventArgs e` param and passing `e.Graphics` to object of my class from ClassLib thingy i created to separate main/form logic and model files.

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            update();
            foreach (Vehicle entity in entitySet)
            {
                entity.draw(e.Graphics);
            }
        }
```

As i understood from quick search, the fact that i am using windows dependency itself outside winforms project causes this exception: `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: "System.Drawing.Common is not supported on this platform."`
But the extremely confusing part is, im already on win10, so the exception message doesnt make any sense to me.

Honestly, i have no idea where to even begin. This is too confusing for me to understand possible fix without changing whole project

Comment: Which .NET Core version are you using? NET 5, 6 and 7 are actually .NET *Core* 5, 6 and 7, not .NET Framework. Unless you target a Windows-specific runtime in your `csproj` you're creating a cross-platform application

Comment: Are you trying to migrate a .NET Framework WinForms application to .NET 6 perhaps? Otherwise why not start from scratch with a WinForms project template?

Comment: The version is .NET Core 3.1 for both application and class lib

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 reaches [End Of Life in 3 weeks](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core). That's worse than going out of support. Use .NET 6 instead. That's a Long-Term-Support version that will be supported until 2024. In any case, you need to target Windows. Both Visual Studio's and `dotnet new` templates will use the correct target. The target framework will be `net6.0-window` not `net6.0-window`

Comment: strange thing, i dont see .NET 6.0 anywhere, i even downloaded fresh installer (mvs2019). The newest is 5.0 (it says support ended) and on 3.1 it says "long term support". So i am even more confused now : )

Comment: .NET 5 reached EOL 9 months ago. The current version of Visual Studio is 2022 BUT .NET Core itself isn't part of VS. It's an independent download. It's even included in Ubuntu 22.04 now. On Windows you can download the SDK from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0 and use any editor you want. You can create a new project using `dotnet new ....` from the command line. I think the WinForms template is `winforsm`  so `dotnet new winforms` will create a new Winforms project

Comment: You still need VS 2022 for the interactive designer though

Comment: I just switched to Jetbrains Rider, same code in new project (version 4.8) works perfectly

Comment: There's no .NET Core 4.8. .NET Framework 4.8 is a completely different runtime. If you want to create a .NET Framework 4.8 project in Visual Studio all you had to do was select the correct template

Comment: What *do* you want to do? Create a .NET Framework or .NET Core application? They are different runtimes